# Неверной значение при подсчете строк из текстового файла

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* initialText;
    char** text;
    int i, countofstr;
    text = (char**) malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        text [i] = (char*) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    }

    initialText = fopen("Text.txt", "r");
    countofstr = 0;

    /*ЦИКЛ для подсчета количества строк и записи строк в массив text[n][m]*/
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        fgets(text[i], 100, initialText);

        if (strcmp(text[i], "") == 0)
        {
            break;    //если строка пустая, т.е. выход   из цикла.
        }

        countofstr++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", countofstr);
    puts(text[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Имеется отформатированый текст(Text.txt), в котором строки нет дополнительных пробелов между строками. В самом тексте может быть не более 100 строк и 100 символов в строке. Необходимо ввести текст в двумерный массив text[n][m](n-адресс строки; m - адресс символа) и посчитать количество строк в переменную countofstr. Для этого был написан цикл for, однако после его выполнении в переменной countofstr неверное значение.

Пример:

> Text.txt:
>   abcde
>   abcde
>   abcde

Результат работы программы:

> 18
>   abcde

Comment: Проверяйте возвращаемое значение fgets и используйте feof. потому как если ему больше нечего читать он вернет NULL при этом сама строка останется не измененной (а в строке после malloc может быть все что угодно, она не заполнена нулями). И `text[i][0]==0` гораздо более эффективная проверка на то, что строка пустая чем strcmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что произойдет по достижении конца файла? В очередной `text[i]` ничего не будет прочтено, но мусор, который там лежит, не даст закончить цикл. Пока не пройдет 100 итераций или пока случайно в `text[i]` первым не будет лежать нулевой символ...

Проверяйте возврат `fgets` или зануляйте все `text[i]`. Хотя сама идея вот так, заранее, выделять массив 100 на 100 лично мне не очень импонирует.

Answer (score 0):

Усовершенствуйте цикл , приблизительно так

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){

  char * str = fgets(text[i], 100, initialText);
  if (str == NULL){
    break; /*ошибка чтение или конец файла*/  
  }    
  countofstr++;
}
```